# PlotLegends in 4D plot

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a data set consisting of 4 points. Each point has 4 columns. I want to plot that data set with 4D color function where 4th column of each dataset will be plotted by the color function. The range of the 4th column is `{2, 9}`. However the `PlotLegends` bar is showing values ranging `{0, 1}`.

```
 rs13pts1 = {{1, .2, .6, 6}, {1.2, .4, .8, 7}, {1.4, .6, 1, 8}, {1.6, .8, 1.2, 9}};

Block[{i = 1}, 
 ListPointPlot3D[rs13pts1[[All, ;; 3]], PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 
    ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][rs13pts1[[i++, 4]]]], 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend["RedGreenSplit"]]]
```

Comment: "The range of 4th column is 2-6" - but the fourth coordinates of your points are outside that specified range; what do you actually want?

Comment: Now it is corrected. However problem not solved!

Comment: Like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/poy1D.png)?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely, Could you please post the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rs13pts1 = {{1, .2, .6, 6}, {1.2, .4, .8, 7}, {1.4, .6, 1, 8}, {1.6, .8, 1.2, 9}};
```

I'd do

```
Block[{i = 1}, 
 ListPointPlot3D[rs13pts1[[All, ;; 3]], PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][
      Rescale[rs13pts1[[i++, 4]], {2, 9}, {0, 1}]] &), 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"RedGreenSplit", {2, 9}}]]]
```

[image]

where I

1. added `PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]` just for the colors of the points to be more visible in this example;
2. altered `PlotLegends` by adding the interval `{2, 9}` to the `BarLegend`;
3. `Rescale`d the `ColorFunction` from the interval `{0, 1}` to `{2, 9}`.